# Why I can't edit my invoice template?

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I have changed the invoiced template to add new parameters before product table. The problem is the changes is not showing when I print the invoices.

The file I am changing is located at `\app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php` and `\app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Abstract.php`

I have tried to delete the archives because Magento should show me the errors but there are not errors. The invoice still printing and not showing the changes.

I checked all modules overrides and in `code/local/Mage...` and I don´t overriding this files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to **rewrite** properly the `Invoice.php` in local with the rewrite `xml` configuration and not just averriding it in local. [more info](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)
2. The `Abstract.php` of course it should be overrided in local and not rewritten because an abstract class can't be rewritted.
3. Dont forget to clean your Magento and browser cache.